# How to find a substring from some text in a file and store it in a bash variable?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file named config.txt which has following data:

```
ABC_PATH=xxx/xxx
IMAGE=docker.name.net:3000/apache:1.8.109.1
NAMESPACE=xxx
```

Now I am running a shell script in which I want to store 1.8.109.1 (this value may differ, rest will remain same) in a variable, maybe using sed, awk or any other linux tool.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work.

`ver="$(cat config.txt | grep apache: | cut -d: -f3)"`

`grep apache:` will find the line that has the text 'apache:' in it.

`-d` specifies what delimiters to use. In this case : is set as the delimiter.
`-f` is used to select the specific field (array index, starting at 1) of the resulting list obtained after delimiting by :

Thus, -f3 selects the 3rd occurence of the delimited list.

The version info is now captured in the variable $ver

Comment: sorry, can't upvote an answer that invokes a process that isn't needed. Can be rewritten as `ver=$(grep apache: config.txt | cut ...)` ... Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
cat config.txt | grep apache: | cut -d: -f3
```

Comment: i thought the problem here was to extract the value.. you could just copy my code into a script and be able to fill a variable with that